# Analysing Eyetracking EDF Files in Python

Tags: python, eye-tracking

It's been quite some time since I used Python as I've been focusing on R in recent months.

I've been using eye-tracking in Opensesame recently. I've placed Eyelink Logs 'PreBeep1' with content "PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad" and 'PostBeep2' with content "PostBeep2" in the trial timeline.

Between these Eyetracking Logs is the part of each trial I want to analyse eye movement.

I've never worked with analysing eye-tracking data before and I'm not sure where to start.

Can anyone offer advice, such as useful libraries, how to extract/analyse data etc. Or perhaps even relevant example code.

I want to be able to identify if/when participants moved away from fixation during the period of interest and by how much.

I'm told this is not the most complicated eye-tracking data to look at, but as I've said I'm knew to it.

Thanks for taking the time to read and consider this.

I've attached an example file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ur549kx0oamo6j/P10E2C.edf

Comment: A quick Google search turned up [this](http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/devices/eyelink/). Not sure if it's helpful though...

Comment: Thanks for that but that's the pylink installation page. I've already installed and run Opensesame with pylink and collect the data.

Comment: I see, so you're wanting to analyze the collected data. I assume the EDF files are unicode, do you know? utf-8, latin-1, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure. However, it seems they can be converted to .txt files. I'm going to look into doing that and seeing what I can do with the data.

Comment: Sounds good. Let us know what you find out and how we can help!

Comment: EDF files can indeed be converted to asc files using software that comes with the eyetracker. From there the data will need to be shaped and that is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893467/shaping-data-in-python - Granted the data in that thread had already been mined from the asc and written to a csv.

Comment: I think I could help you a bit, but your dropbox link to the EDF is  broken :o(

Comment: might be a little bit too late but I did code a package to do eye data analysis with python :)
write me back if you are still in the game!

Comment: Hi @DaniPaniz. I've actually recently taken on a new eye-tracking dataset. I'm interested in looking at your package for sure.

Comment: great, the code is messy and badly documented (INAP), can I mail you?