# Shaping Data in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm currently working with data generated by eyelink. The csv (transformed from asc) is basically one large sequential list, i.e. columns are not created, so for example a row will have 'start_trial 1' and the following row will have x and y coordinates and the following N rows will also before coming to 'PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad' row and eventually 'start_trial 2' row.

I was wondering if anyone has any advice on how to manipulate this 'stacked' data and transform it into long form data?

Here is what the data looks like when pulled from the csv:

```
MSG 12892743 start_trial    1   SCNB    
12892743      757.0   361.7  5916.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892744 PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad SCNB
12892744      756.7   361.7  5920.0 ... SCNB    
12892745      756.1   362.2  5924.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892746 order of frames:   SCNB    
12892746      755.8   362.3  5928.0 ... SCNB    
12892747      756.7   362.3  5927.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892748 crosshair  SCNB    
12892748      757.8   361.8  5928.0 ... SCNB    
12892749      758.4   361.8  5930.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892750 sketchpad  SCNB    
12892750      758.1   361.7  5934.0 ... SCNB    
12892751      758.3   361.7  5938.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892752 sketchpad  SCNB    
12892752      759.1   361.9  5948.0 ... SCNB    
12892753      760.4   362.7  5956.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892754 sketchpad  SCNB    
12892754      761.7   363.5  5964.0 ... SCNB    
12892755      763.9   364.0  5966.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892756 buffer1    SCNB    
12892756      765.6   364.1  5970.0 ... SCNB    
12892757      766.2   364.3  5972.0 ... SCNB    
MSG 12892758 Diode1 SCNB    
12892758      765.2   364.3  5973.0 ... SCNB    
12892759      764.1   364.5  5964.0 ... SCNB    
12892760      763.9   364.7  5955.0 ... SCNB
```

Ideally I'd like to have individual columns for:

```
Trial ID (SCNB shown above)
Frame ID (PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad above)
X-CoOr (757.0 above)
Y-CoOr (361.7 above)
Time (5916.0 above)
```

Delimiters are \t in the csv file if that helps.

As can be seen the data is written row-after-row sequentially from top-to-bottom instead of being organised into columns as I want to shape them.

the '...' are actual values also.

Regarding the column that will contain Frame IDs such as 'start_trial' and 'PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad' I would ideally want the name of that frame repeated in the column until encountering a new one.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Output should look like this:

```
Trial ID       Frame ID                 X-CoOr    Y-CoOr    Time 
  SCNB           Start_Trial              757.0    361.7    5916.0 
  SCNB           PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad   756.7    361.7    5920.0
  SCNB           PreBeep1_1st_Sketchpad   756.1    362.2    5924.0
```

Thanks for taking the time to read.

EDIT:

Here is the code I was working with:

```
file2 = open('P1E2E_Both_New_trial_data.csv', 'rb')
Long_Format = open('P1E2E_Long_Format.csv', 'w')
writer1 = csv.writer(Long_Format, delimiter = '\t')

#First create column headings
columns = ["Trial ID"] + ['Frame ID'] + ['X-CoOr'] + ['Y-CoOr'] + ['Time']
writer1.writerow(columns)

reader1 = csv.reader(file2, delimiter = '\t')

for row in reader1:
    # if statement here to skip blank lines
    if len(row) > 1:
        if 'start_trial' in row[1]:
            label = [row[3]] + ['start_trial']
            writer1.writerow(label)



file2.close()   # <---IMPORTANT
Long_Format.close()
```

The output for the above is:

```
Trial ID      Frame ID      X-CoOr     Y-CoOr     Time

SCNB          start_trial

RCL           start_trial

SCR           start_trial
```

... and so on.

My problem lies in that I don't know where to go from here. My approach would be terribly inefficient even it were to work. I don't know how to tell python to continue reading the lines after the label 'Start_Trial' in the if statement and to write the x and y CoOr values from row[2] and row[3] in the appropriate columns after said label. Does that makes sense?

Comment: what does `sapaying` mean??

Comment: What part of the process do you need help with?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: @andi I made a typo but meant to say 'shaping'. Code-Apprentice I have already shaped the data to add Trial IDs (e.g. SCNB) but I'm not sure how to shape the data further to long format as demonstrated in the edit above. Thanks again folks for taking the time to read.

Comment: What's your approach? Have you tried to write any code?

Comment: @Trimax I've edited the original post to show the code I was trying to write to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are the frame-start lines delemeted by the same character as the other lines?

Comment: @aruisdante start_trial uses the same delimiter yes. Although there is a numerical value before the label that is not separated by a delimiter that I don't need and hence why I've used a string rather than a row[number] to write to csv. All labels have a numerical value before them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that all lines have the same delemeter, this problem isn't as bad as it looks.

The key is realizing that all of the frame lines start with the key `'MSG'`:

```
import csv
# Header values
FRAME_KEY = 'MSG'
FRAME_IDX = 0
TRIAL_ID_KEY = 'Trial ID'
TRIAL_ID_IDX = 3
FRAME_ID_KEY = 'Frame ID'
FRAME_ID_IDX = 2
# Data values
XCOR_KEY     = 'X-CoOr'
XCOR_IDX     = 1
YCOR_KEY     = 'Y-CoOr'
YCOR_IDX     = 2
TIME_KEY     = 'Time'
TIME_IDX     = 3

IN_DELIM = '\t'
OUT_DELIM= '\t'

OUT_HEADER = [TRIAL_ID_KEY, FRAME_ID_KEY, XCOR_KEY, YCOR_KEY, TIME_KEY]

with open('P1E2E_Both_New_trial_data.csv', 'rb') as in_file, open('P1E2E_Long_Format.csv') as out_file:
    in_reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimeter = IN_DELIM)
    out_writer= csv.DictWriter(out_file, OUT_HEADER, delimeter = OUT_DELIM)
    out_writer.writeheader()
    current_frame = None
    current_trial = None
    for row in in_reader:
        if row[FRAME_IDX] == FRAME_KEY:
            # Means we're at the start of a new frame
            current_frame = row[FRAME_ID_IDX]
            current_trial = row[TRIAL_ID_IDX]
        else:
            # Means we're in a data row
            out_row = dict()
            out_row[FRAME_ID_KEY] = current_frame
            out_row[TRIAL_ID_KEY] = current_trial
            out_row[XCOR_KEY]     = row[XCOR_IDX]
            out_row[YCOR_KEY]     = row[YCOR_IDX]
            out_row[TIME_KEY]     = row[TIME_IDX]
            out_writer.writerow(out_row)
```

Basically, when you hit a row with the `'MSG'` key, you know you're starting a new frame. Otherwise you write out the data. `DictWriter` makes it easy to do this automatically without having to worry about order (the order is defined by the `OUT_HEADER`)

Comment: Thanks a million. I adjusted TRIAL_ID_IDX to equal 1 as the numbers before the trial ID are not separated by delimiters and as a result affect the list index range. It works perfectly cheers. I can live with the numbers in the ID. Thanks once again, you've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the answer submitted by @aruisdante. This is because the original code did not record every instance of Frame IDs. I noticed this when doing a count of start_trial frame IDs and they fell short of the known total.

Here is the amended code:

```
FRAME_KEY = 'MSG'
FRAME_IDX = 0
FRAME_ID_KEY = 'Frame ID'
FRAME_ID_IDX = 1
TRIAL_ID_KEY = 'Trial ID'
TRIAL_ID_IDX = 2
# Data values
XCOR_KEY     = 'X-CoOr'
XCOR_IDX     = 1
YCOR_KEY     = 'Y-CoOr'
YCOR_IDX     = 2
TIME_KEY     = 'Time'
TIME_IDX     = 3

IN_DELIM = '\t'
OUT_DELIM= '\t'

OUT_HEADER = [TRIAL_ID_KEY, FRAME_ID_KEY, XCOR_KEY, YCOR_KEY, TIME_KEY]

currentframecount = 0
currentframecount1 = 0
out_row = dict()


with open('P1E2E_Both_New_trial_data.csv', 'rb') as in_file, open('P1E2E_Long_Format.csv', 'w') as out_file:
in_reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter = IN_DELIM)
out_writer= csv.DictWriter(out_file, OUT_HEADER, delimiter = OUT_DELIM)
out_writer.writeheader()
current_frame = None
current_trial = None

for row in in_reader:
    if row[FRAME_IDX] == FRAME_KEY:
        # Means we're at the start of a new frame
        current_frame = row[FRAME_ID_IDX]
        current_trial = row[TRIAL_ID_IDX]

        #out_row[TRIAL_ID_KEY] = current_trial
        #out_row[FRAME_ID_KEY] = current_frame
        #out_writer.writerow(out_row)
        #if 'start_trial' in current_frame:
        #   currentframecount += 1
        #  print currentframecount
        # Here ensures that 'start_trail' labels are recorded
        if 'start_trial' in row[FRAME_ID_IDX]:
            out_row[FRAME_ID_KEY] = row[FRAME_ID_IDX]
            out_writer.writerow(out_row)


    else:
        # Means we're in a data row
        #Here write everything except 'start_trial' to ensure no repetition of this particular label
        if 'start_trial' not in current_frame:
            out_row[FRAME_ID_KEY] = current_frame # think this is pulling value from last if statement on current_frame

            out_row[TRIAL_ID_KEY] = current_trial
            out_row[XCOR_KEY]     = row[XCOR_IDX]
            out_row[YCOR_KEY]     = row[YCOR_IDX]
            out_row[TIME_KEY]     = row[TIME_IDX]
            out_writer.writerow(out_row)
```